# How to split my python script into two and have them act like one?

Tags: python, xml, multithreading, opencv

UPDATE: I tried adding the part of the code I wanted preloaded in a different script, and then I imported the script. But as I thought would happen it just did the same thing. Any help?

So I am pretty new to python and opencv and I was wondering if you can help me do something. My python script has a section that takes 22 seconds to load (XML file). How can I put that part into another script and still use the variable the XML file was loaded into. I want this because I need things to be instant..and I only need to load the XML when a new user is added to the facial recognition algorithm.

Full Script:

```
import cv2

import config
import face




# Load training data into model
print 'Loading training data...'
model = cv2.face.createEigenFaceRecognizer()
model.load(config.TRAINING_FILE)
print 'Training data loaded!'
# Initialize camer and box.
camera = config.get_camera()



print 'Press Ctrl-C to quit.'

while True:
# Check if capture should be made.


print 'looking for face...'
# Check for the positive face and unlock if found.
image = camera.read()
# Convert image to grayscale.
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
# Get coordinates of single face in captured image.
result = face.detect_single(image)
if result is None:
    print 'Could not detect single face!  Check the image in capture.pgm' \
          ' to see what was captured and try again with only one face            visible.'
continue
x, y, w, h = result
# Crop and resize image to face.
crop = face.resize(face.crop(image, x, y, w, h))
# Test face against model.


label, confidence = model.predict(crop)
print 'Predicted {0} face with confidence {1} (lower is more    confident).'.format(
    'POSITIVE' if label == config.POSITIVE_LABEL else 'NEGATIVE',
    confidence)
if label == config.POSITIVE_LABEL: 
    print 'Recognized face!'
else:
    print 'Did not recognize face!'
```

Section I want to pre-load in a separate script so I can save time:

```
# Load training data into model
print 'Loading training data...'
model = cv2.face.createEigenFaceRecognizer()
model.load(config.TRAINING_FILE)
print 'Training data loaded!'
```

I want to be able to use model, but without having to load every time. So, I would just load once and then run the other part of the script which would be instant.

Please help me, Thanks.

Comment: Please fix the indentation, it matters in Python.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time using stack. My code is properly indented in reality, think something went wrong when I copied it here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just create another script with the first part (let's say preload.py) and then just import it in your second script

```
...
import preload
...
```

and then you can reference variables from the first script just by using:

```
preload.model
```

Comment: I tried that, but it would load the XML file twice. Any idead on what I can do?

Comment: last comment was wrong, sorry. when I import, it actually acts exactly the same if I had the code in one script. I want to be able to import first at a different time. And then be able to use the second script when needed (use the loaded model from the other script)